# Getting error over posting date in php

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I am working on PHP to make an online shop.

I have my order table.

```
<?php
  $itemno = $_POST['itemno'];
  $qty = $_POST['qty'];
  $price = $_POST['price'];
  $orderno = rand(0,100);
  $firstname =  $_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $streetaddress= $_POST['streetaddress'];
  $city = $_POST['city'];
  $state = $_POST['state'];
  $postcode2 = $_POST['postcode2'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];

  $dat=date("Y-m-d");

  include_once('config.php');
  $save_items = mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders (itemno,qty,price,orderno,firstname,lastname,streetaddress,city,state,postcode2,email,phone,dat)VALUES('$itemno','$qty','$price','$orderno','$firstname','$lastname','$streetaddress','$city','$state','$postcode2','$email','$phone','$dat')");

        if($save_items){
            echo '1';
        }else{
            echo '0';
        }
?>
```

Two things I need help:

- I want to access the latest date order in top in order view page.
  Here is my mysql "select * from orders ORDER BY dat ".
  What change i should do so i get access the latest date order.
- I got error in Phone number it comes like this "2147483647".

Comment: *I got error in Phone number it comes like this "2147483647".* What is the error?

Comment: @luweiqi i got this number 2147483647 in every order  table of every phone number.

Comment: 1. `... ORDER BY dat DESC;` 2. What's your expected output for phone number?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul the phone number which will post by customer .

Comment: Do `echo $phone;` before executing the query and see what output you're getting.

Comment: Now its working.. I have changed the Phone number fron integer to varchar(20) ..Its all right now..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1) I want to access the latest date order in top in order view page. Here is my mysql "select * from orders ORDER BY dat ". What change i should do so i get access the latest date order.

You can order by id of table:

`"select * from orders ORDER BY id DESC"` -and this you will get latest order first

*2) I got error in Phone number it comes like this "2147483647" .*

Remove single quotes from $phone if it is integer column

```
$save_items = mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders (itemno,qty,price,orderno,firstname,lastname,streetaddress,city,state,postcode2,email,phone,dat)VALUES('$itemno','$qty','$price','$orderno','$firstname','$lastname','$streetaddress','$city','$state','$postcode2','$email',$phone,'$dat')");
```

Comment: That ORDER by id is working... but Phone number is not coming.. any other solution.

Comment: Now its working.. I have changed the Phone number fron integer to varchar(20) ..Its all right now..Thanks